# How can I access the Parse Cloud Code hosted in AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, parse-platform

I want my app in iOS to verify user phone numbers, but that would require that I write code in a place called Cloud Code in Parse.  The Parse Server is hosted in Amazon Web Services but I cannot find exactly where the Cloud Code is.  How could I access it?

I already tried looking it up and the closest thing I got is to use Webhooks in my Parse Dashboard- with no real success.

Comment: Did you host in amazon ec2 instance? It will be better if you can give some idea about the current hosting setup.

Comment: Yes, it's Parse Server on amazon ec2.

Comment: You would need to deploy files that contain your javascript code to the ec2 instance.  Your parse config points to a single file that is the entry point for your javascript cloud code.

Comment: How would I deploy and access them though? I tried to use CLI.

Comment: @WannaInternet I  have added my custom code in main.js in  ```/opt/bitnami/cloud/``` but I get 141 error code. Any help?